# How to get the Check box status in Citrix Environment in Uipath Automation

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath

[image]

These are the Check Boxes which i need to check the status and if these are not selected I need to check the box , as this is a citrix environment not able to get the correct/complete selector of that check box.

Tried Element Exist , Anchor Base & Get Attribute ,all these activities are giving the output that is False even when the box selected.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In citrix environment I use [Image Exists](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/image-found) activity of UI path to get value of a checkbox. I am not sure if there is a better way of doing this but it gives accurate results. You can also use [Click Image](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/click-image) activity to set the value of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a recent version, you can perform native Citrix automation, without the need for image automation, check this out:
https://studio.uipath.com/docs/about-native-citrix-automation

If you configure your environment for native automation, you can use the "Get attribute" activity and that should expose the state of the checkbox as well.